# Json load is giving me a JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes only in terminal

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to pass json through terminal parameters:

```py
import json
import sys
import requests
import platform
from winreg import *
from pathlib import Path
import datetime


def show_gifs(giffavs, folder):
    value = json.loads(giffavs)["_state"]["favorites"]
    print(f'found {len(value)} faved gifs')
    for count, el in enumerate(value):
        print(f'➡{count}: {el["url"]}')
        if el["url"].split('.')[-1] != 'gif':
            el["url"] += '.gif'
        download_gif(el["url"], folder)


...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #set time value and get JSON from args if exist
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    data = str(sys.argv[1]) #here I get my JSON data I used to just make it a str value but now I want to take it from gicen parameters


    #look for right folder and create it
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        if len(sys.argv) == 3:
            folder = sys.argv[2]
        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
            with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders') as key:
                folder = QueryValueEx(key, '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}')[0]
        else:
            folder = str(Path.home()) + '/Downloads'

        folder += '/DiscordFavoriteGif(' + now.strftime("%d") + '.' + now.strftime("%b") + '.' + now.strftime(
            "%Y") + '_' + now.strftime("%H") + now.strftime("%M") + now.strftime("%S") + ')'
        Path(folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        show_gifs(data, folder)
    else:
        print('too many arguments')
```

when I write manually my json in the data variable
`data = 'MYJSON'`
it works but when I try to use the same data in my terminal
`python DownloadFavoriteGIF.py MYJSON`
I get a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

which is weird because it's the exact same data, do you know where it could come from ?

**EDIT**

my json look like this I just removed the url for privacy issue:
`{"_state":{"favorites":[{"url":"url","src":" url","width":1032,"height":1000,"format":"IMAGE"},{"url":" url","src":" url ","width":247,"height":387,"format":"IMAGE"},{"url":" url ","src":" url ","width":640,"height":358,"format":"VIDEO"},{"url":" url ","src":" url ","width":640,"height":516,"format":"VIDEO"},{"width":632,"height":640,"src":" url ","format":"VIDEO"}],"timesFavorited":6},"_version":2}`

Comment: One reason (maybe the only reason) I can think of why this could be happening is that you have a problem with your quoting on the terminal. Could you give us the actual command you are executing that produces this error? (I'm assuming your data isn't actually `MYJSON`.) You might also try printing your `data` variable to see if it actually contains what you think it contains.

Comment: Make sure you put the JSON in quotes in the shell.

Comment: here's the JSON I use I removed the url for privacy safety, `{"_state":{"favorites":[{"url":"url","src":" url","width":1032,"height":1000,"format":"IMAGE"},{"url":" url","src":" url ","width":247,"height":387,"format":"IMAGE"},{"url":" url ","src":" url ","width":640,"height":358,"format":"VIDEO"},{"url":" url ","src":" url ","width":640,"height":516,"format":"VIDEO"},{"width":632,"height":640,"src":" url ","format":"VIDEO"}],"timesFavorited":6},"_version":2}`

Comment: How are you quoting it at the shell? If it's unquoted (and this is a POSIX-y shell), the shell will think the `"`s are meant for its use and not part of the JSON itself, so it'll take them out before Python gets started at all. If you want to make sure the data makes it through unchanged, put single quotes at the very start and very end.

Comment: BTW, `data = 'MYJSON'` isn't a valid shell assignment (it's not legal to have spaces around the `=` in POSIX-flavored shell languages). It _has_ to be `data='MYJSON'`, without the spaces.

Comment: If this is a Windows shell instead of a POSIXy one the quoting requirements are a bit different, and I'm not an expert in them. But the point remains that you need to quote your values appropriately so the shell (whichever one it is) doesn't change them.

Comment: I'm using windows CMD and `data = 'MYJSON'` isn't typed in the shell it's replacing the area in my script accessing the argv

Comment: Then I'd suggest looking at this as a cmd.exe problem instead of a Python problem, if you know that your code works right when cmd.exe isn't involved.

Comment: ...the Python side of a [mre] could probably be as simple as `import json, sys; json.loads(sys.argv[1])` -- no reason to have all these other modules involved if you can produce the error with something simpler.

Comment: You could also just have your Python code _print_ the JSON as it sees it, and compare that to the original string to see exactly what's going wrong.